# CSS Buttons with 'particular' animation

Tags: html, css, button

Does anyone have any idea on how to implement an HTML+CSS button that once clicked has an animation like this one?

[image]

Source: http://www.materialup.com/posts/shinebutton

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm thinking that's a no - not this year at least.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/recreating-the-twitter-heart-animation/ good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with **Twitter's "fave" animation**

```css
.heart {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: url(https://cssanimation.rocks/images/posts/steps/heart.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: fave-heart 1s steps(28);
}
.heart:hover {
  background-position: -2800px 0;
  transition: background 1s steps(28);
}
@keyframes fave-heart {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -2800px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
```

**[More](https://cssanimation.rocks/twitter-fave/)**

Comment: Thank you very much, this is an awesome result!